# How can I get the Moustachio achievements in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: achievements, left-4-dead-2

There are two achievements related to Moustachio in Left 4 Dead 2.

These are the descriptions:

1. **Gong Show** - Prove you are stronger than Moustachio.
2. **Stache Whacker** - Prove you are faster than Moustachio.

Do you know how can I get them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,

- **Gong Show**: You need to inject an adrenaline and hit the gong at the strong man game, see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dN1OTQfVP8)
- **Stache Whacker**: You need to quickly hit the Moustachios on another game (don't know the English name), see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o8IKa34W9Q)

I got them both, it's not difficult.

Comment: The toughest part of these is getting yelled at by your team for burning an adrenaline!

Comment: @not, achievements are more important :)

Comment: It's worth noting that for stache whacker you can restart the game, so you don't have to be all that fast. You can also shoot Mustachio instead of hitting him. Uses up ammo, but far more satisfying!

Comment: thank you, they seems quite easy and funny :) I will try to get them

Comment: You can also have friends help you with the Stache Whacker achievement. It will award to anyone who hit him at least once and it's a lot easier to accomplish if you've got at least 1 person covering the 3 open sides of the game.

Answer (score 6):

You can get **Gong Show** by getting a tank to hit the gong for you. Much more fun than using up your adrenaline!

Comment: You also need to wait for a tank to appear when you're there... it could appear anywhere thanks to the AI Director, but I guess it's possible

Comment: this could be fun :)

Answer (score -2):

Getting "Gong Show" and "Stache Whacker" isn't difficult. Both achievements are based on the same area, chapter, person, etc.

Shooting the mini Moustachio's are much more faster for quick-player people, but you can also use melee weapons, for those who are patient of getting the achievement.

Gong Show is just taking and adrenaline, stabbing it into your leg, and using a melee weapon to hit the block.